# Data_length in 'show table status'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find out the size of a database table. I ran the 'show table status' query, and i have the data_length parameter in the result. Does this represent the actual size of the database table?

Comment: Or is the data_length plus the index_length the actual size of the database table?

Comment: Not sure but this reference will help you calculate the record size http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For InnoDB, the `data_length` is an *estimate* of the table size, in bytes, not counting secondary indexes.  The documentation says this is the "size of the data file" but that language assumes you have data in a separate file, which isn't always the case with InnoDB.

The size of a table is a bit fuzzy for InnoDB, because InnoDB also stores some copies of rows globally in the rollback segment, and there are other uses of on-disk storage (data dictionary, change buffer).

You should also add `index_length`, which is the size of secondary indexes.